# How do I find out about the standards for writing regression packages in R?

Tags: r, package, regression, logistic-regression

As part of my job, I need to fit a bunch of 'generalised logistic' (GL)* regression models (with some special restrictions that are not pertinent to this question). There is no package that currently allows me to do this so I have written my own function which just optimises the likelihood. It is messy, and not that general at the moment as it is tailored towards the specific job I need it to do.

I was thinking about turning it into a more general package, it would be the first I had written.

**My questions are:**

1) Am I missing a trick, and is it possible to just bolt on my own link function to GLM rather than writing it from scratch?

2) Is their information somewhere on the standards expected for a regression package, e.g., expected "summary" output, standardised names for output, standard formula input, etc?

3) Are there any good "how to write a package in R" resources that you could *recommend*?

I'm happy to be more specific if needed. Many thanks for any replies.

Best.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function

Comment: I may be missing something, but what is wrong with `stats::glm()`, `glmnet::glmnet()` or `caret::train(..., method = "glm")`?

Comment: I also may be missing something, but I don't think that those packages fit the model I am after, the "generalised logistic" regression model. It is logistic regression with more parameters to do more things.  If you are interested, I want to model the probability of passing a child development item based on an underlying condition.  In this case, a proportion of some of these children with the conditions may never pass an item, so I need to estimate an upper asymptote, not have it specified as 1, as it is in the logistic model.

Comment: I think you got the answer for your problem, but answering your 3rd question: [*R Packages*](https://r-pkgs.org/) by Hadley Wickham and Jennifer Bryan is a very good (and free) source about package writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to create your own GLM link function. You can do the following:

```r
my_link_function <- function(mu) 
{
  # Body of your link function
}

my_inverse_link_function <- function(eta) 
{
  # Body of your inverse link function
}

my_derivative_function <- function(eta)
{
  # function describing dmu / delta
}

my_valid_eta_function <- function(eta)
{
  # return TRUE if eta is in domain of inverse_link_function, otherwise FALSE
}

my_link <- list(linkfun  = my_link_function,
                linkinv  = my_inverse_link_function,
                mu.eta   = my_derivative_function,
                valideta = my_valid_eta_function,,
                name     = "my_link")
class(my_link) <- "link-glm"
```

Now you can do this:

```r
glm(my_var1 ~ my_var2, family = binomial(my_link))
```

Comment: Hi, this looks great, thank you for your help!  Will I be able to find this for the logistic regression model if I dig about in the GLM function, just to use as a template? You don't know where abouts I should start looking first by any chance do you?

Comment: If you just want to do a logistic regression, you don't need to write your own link function. There's already a good one built in. You just need to write `glm(var_y ~ var_x, family = binomial("logit"))` . You can't look at the logit link function source directly in R, as the function appears to be written in C. Are you sure you need to write your own link function?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. yes, I definitely need to write my own link function, as I want a generalised logistic regression model, specifically, I need to be able to estimate the upper asymptote, rather than assume it is 1. Don't worry, though, you have put me on the right track and I'm sure I will work it out from here.